# How do to sort list and memorize each original id in R?

Tags: r

I would sort a list from biggest to the lowest , but I would also memorise the id of each element. for exemple :

```
vect <- c(3,1,7,5)
```

I would have a vector with 7,5,3,1 but also associate the original position in vect:

3 to 7

4 to 5

1 to 3

2 to 1

Comment: Try `z<-order(vect,decreasing=TRUE)`. The `z` object will keep the indices (3,4,1,2) and with `vect[z]` you sort `vect`.

Comment: thanks that worked for me